# NegotiateHandler - Where does the windows identity come from?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication

I'm currently playing around with the negotiate-AuthenticationHandler. What I try to create is an API running in the intranet on a Windows server and any user calling this API is automatically authenticated using their current Windows account. That's what I thought this authentication handler is for. I created a very simple API that just authenticates and returns the current identity name. This way I wanted to check if the identity is the calling user or just the current authenticated user on the environment the server is running on.

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors(x =>
{
    x.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader();
});

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**Controller.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("controller")]
    public class Controller : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("auth")]
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
        public string Get()
        {
            return this.User.Identity!.Name!;
        }
    }
}
```

When running this API locally and sending a request using Swagger I get authenticated and my domain and user name are returned. When I send a request using Postman I don't get authenticated but I get status 401. I tried to debug the Authentication and authorization middleware as well as the NegotiateHandler.

The NegotiateHandler is never really called. `HandleRequestAsync` is called but returns immediately because `Options.DeferToServer` is `true` and both `HandleAuthenticateAsync` and `HandleChallengeAsync` are never called (Symbols loaded but breakpoint never hit)

Both the authentication and authorization middleware don't seem to have any effect because when both middleware are called the Windows identity is already present in the HttpContext.

So I don't know where the identity comes from and if it's the identity of the calling client or the identity of the environment the server is running on. Also, I don't know why I get authenticated when using Swagger but not if I use Postman. I could not identify any headers sent by Postman that would help to identify me.

Can anyone clarify this and, if I am wrong, tell me what Negotiate is good for?

**EDIT:**

When I specify Urls in the `appsettings.json` to listen on `0.0.0.0` Swagger, which returned the Identity Name before now also runs into 401. Why does this happen?

```
"Kestrel": {
  "Endpoints": {
    "Http": {
      "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:45789"
    },
    "Https": {
      "Url": "https://0.0.0.0:45790"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The calling client has to support the flow that follows the 401 challenge. Looks like one of your clients does so, the other does not. You can read more by googling the "401 challenge" key phrase. [Example result](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/windows-authentication-http-request-flow-in-iis/ba-p/324645).

Comment: @WiktorZychla Okay thanks I'll have a look at it. Another problem I realized while waiting for a response is that when specifying Kestrel urls `Kestrel > Endpoints > Name > Url` in the `appsettings.json` to listen at `0.0.0.0` even swagger which returned the identity name before now also returns 401. Do you know why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Edge, you probably don't have to input windows username and password even you have protected the webapi with windows authentication. Because Edge integrate windows authentication to local website by default. But this doesn't happen if you using other client or browser, such as chrome, firefox, postman.
To make Egde act normally like other clients. You could choose from the Edge dropdown "more tools" -> "Internet options"-> "Security" tab-> Local intranet" ->" Sites" -> check "Automatically detect intranet network
[image]
Then when you visit the api from swagger, it will prompt for credential.
[image]

Comment: Okay thanks. Before I'll have a look at it, there is immediately a question that pops up. This Windows Authentication should result in a SSO behavior. Does edge save the information locally or somewhere "in the cloud"? So if I login with my account on another device, do I have to authenticate myself again?

Comment: @Kaskorian I don't think it is on cloud. This article may help you with settings. https://helpdesk.thoughtfarmer.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500005844122-How-to-enable-Windows-SSO-login-on-browsers

Comment: Okay I configured the intranet and the behavior to automatically login within the intranet zone. There is only one problem. The negotiate handshake only works on `GET` requests. When I have a route decorated with `HttpGet` the handshake works for both the call through the browser search bar and the call through the angular HTTP client. But when I have for example a POST endpoint the handshakes stops at `401` with the header `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate`